# Where is the "Invalid username" WooCommerce error message coming from?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to modify the text of a WooCommerce error message (for security reasons) but can't seem to find where this particular message is actually coming from.

I'm on the `example.com/shop/my-account/` page (could have been `example.com/my-account/` as well) and purposefully entering wrong username and password for testing.

The relevant HTML part looks exactly like this:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <li>
        <strong>ERROR</strong>
        : Invalid username.
        <a href="http://example.com/shop/my-account/lost-password/">Lost your password?</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to change the `Invalid username` part of the message to something else.

So, I searched for that exact string but can only find instances of `Invalid username or email.` **which obviously does NOT match the error message I'm trying to modify**.

I then checked to see where is the entire HTML part being generated and found that it's being generated in `plugins\woocommerce\templates\notices\error.php`.

Here's the relevant part:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">
    <?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
        <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

So, that error message is coming from a `$messages` array.

### But WHERE can I find the actual message in question?

(so that I can modify it)

Why is the exact match (`Invalid username`) nowhere to be found?

I tried to search for `$messages`, of course, but there's nothing relevant to be found. So, where the heck is that particular error message actually coming from? Even searching in the entire `wp-content` folder doesn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the actual message in question comes from WordPress itself and not WooCommerce.  Specifically try looking in wp-includes/user.php.  If you want to change the message, I would strongly recommend using a hook to do so to prevent losing your modification when WP is updated.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! In `wp-includes/user.php` on line 147 it is: `<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username.` Interestingly, in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` there's also this error message: `<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username, email address or incorrect password.` which is exactly the kind of error message I want to avoid giving potential hackers valuable information. And yes, I know, changing the core files would revert everything back upon the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but in case it can help someone I think that the piece of code you need to modify is located in the function "process_login()" located in the file "woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php" of Woocommerce plugin:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    $message = $user->get_error_message();
    $message = str_replace( '<strong>' . esc_html( $creds['user_login'] ) . '</strong>', '<strong>' . esc_html( $creds['user_login'] ) . '</strong>', $message );
    throw new Exception( $message );
} else {
```

You can change the message before the exception is thrown.(by the way I do not understand the added value of the str_replace since it does nothing).

Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above snippets but its doesn't work for me then I tried this one.

```
function no_wordpress_errors(){
  return 'Invalid credentials';
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'no_wordpress_errors' );
```

Its working for me